# How to easily change a recurring property name in multiple schemas?

Tags: json, jsonschema

To be able to deserialize polymorphic types, I use a type discriminator across many of my JSON objects. E.g., `{ "$type": "SomeType", "otherProperties": "..." }`

For the JSON schemas of *concrete* types, I specify a const value for type.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "$type": { "const": "SomeType" },
    "otherProperties": { "type": "string" }
  }
}
```

This works, but distributes the chosen "$type" property name throughout *many* different JSON schemas. In fact, we are considering renaming it to "__type" to play more nicely with BSON.

Could I have prevented having to rename this property in all affected schemas?

I tried searching for a way to load the property name from elsewhere. As far as I can tell `$ref` only works for property values.

Comment: You can use `allOf` to have multiple schemas apply to the same location, but if you're using tooling which does anything beyond validation (such as code generation), then they likely won't play well with that sort of change. `$ref` works anywhere you have a subschema. If you're only using your schemas for validation, let me know, and I'll show you how to achieve this.

Comment: @Relequestual I use `allOf` quite extensively for my polymorphic hierarchies already, to not have to redefine base properties in all concrete types. E.g. [here](https://github.com/cph-cachet/carp.core-kotlin/pull/351/files#diff-882654ee214c533574f907dff8d41a23b0d123cb6e227f23d3cb038fe3557a61). The problem is the "const" part; it _needs_ to be specified in the concrete types, but the property it specifies is what is currently being duplicated.

Comment: Ok, in which case I'll answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Schema has no ability to dynamically load in key values from other location like you are asking. Specifically because the value will be different, and you want only the key to be loaded from elsewhere.

While you can't do this with JSON Schema, you could use a templating tool such as [Jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/). I've seen this work well at scale.

This would require you have a pre-processing step, but it sounds like that's something you're planning for already, creating some sort of pipeline to generate your schemas.

A word of warning, watch out for existing schema generation tooling. It is often only good for scaffolding, and requires lots of modifications. It sounds like you're building your own, which is likely a better approach.

Comment: I'm manually maintaining them at first, since I figured as much (saw some awful generated schemas). I do see a potential to generate them from `kotlinx.serialization` serial descriptors, but that would be a bigger project. I need the JSON schemas so people not using Kotlin can consume my APIs more easily. More input on why `allOf` doesn't play well with code generation would be appreciated, although it feels like a different question. I may ask when I hit that bump. Thanks!

Comment: My advice would be check out the links on the JSON Schema home page. There's a link to our slack server and regular weekly office hours. Either of those might be a better place for such a question than here =]